# Provide public access to default plugin settings?

Tags: fullcalendar

I must set timeFormat, axisFormat (HH:mm) called from within a 'ready' block!

I read a article from http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern.

And maybe I'm wrong, but I think the only way to set parameters for fullcalendar is to pass it by 'constructor' - I mean:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
                 {
                     title:  'My Event',
                     start:   '2010-06-08T14:30:00',
                     end:     '2010-06-08T15:45:00',
                     allDay: false
                 }
                 // other events here...
             ],
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        timeFormat : {
          "" : "H:mm{ - H:mm}",
          agenda : "H:mm{ - H:mm}"
        },
        axisFormat : "H:mm"
    });
```

But I really need to set those(timeFormat, axisFormat) properties after object initialization...
Is it an implementation bug that those properties cann't be overwritten after?

*I'm using seam, primefaces(with fullcalendar.js). I really don't know is there any other solution... help :)

Answer (score 4):

there is actually an undocumented function for this. use

```
$.fullCalendar.setDefaults({
   // your options here
});
```

i can't guarantee the api won't change in the future though. since this is unofficial, i cant help you beyond this. good luck